# Bicomplex quadratic forms

Tags: normed-spaces, quadratic-forms

The quadratic form associated with a real matrix $Q$ and a real vector $\vec{x}$ is $\langle Q \vec{x}, \vec{x} \rangle$.
The quadratic form associated with a real matrix $Q$ and a complex vector $\vec{x}$ is $\langle Q \vec{x}, \vec{x}^* \rangle$.
What is the quadratic form associated with a real matrix $Q$ and a [bicomplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number) vector $\vec{x}$?

Comment: Definitions are generally given corresponding to what turns out to be useful.  So you may need lots of experience before making your new definition.

Comment: @GEdar yeah I'm realizing that... I'm hoping for a definition that gives me the a real value (the squared norm of x if Q is the identity), but it seems like I can't find any based on conjugation.